# Getting a value from a AngularJS Promise in MeanJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, meanjs

I'm playing around with [MeanJS](http://meanjs.org) recently and I ran into an issue that I'm not well versed in so I'm hoping someone can help here.

I have a angular controller that sets it scope like this:

```
// Find existing Topic
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.topic = Topics.get({
        topicId: $stateParams.topicId
    });
};
```

I this sets the `topic` in the `$scope`. However, I also need to get a value off of the `topic` as well. Lets assume it is a date such as `createdAt`. I need to get this value and then perform another operation on it in order to set another scope value. The problem is, the `$scope.topic` object is an Angular promise. How can I get the value `createdAt` (which is a Date) off of that promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise callback.

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.topic = Topics.get({
        topicId: $stateParams.topicId
    });
    $scope.topic.$promise.then(function(data) {
        // access data.createdAt here
    });
};
```

Its actual also depends on that where you want to use this. So if you want to use this in the view, you can write directly as:

```
<span> Created at: {{topic.createdAt}}</span>
```

Angular will autoupdate that scope variable when data is loaded.

Comment: I tried this exact thing and I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, yet when I look at it in the Chrome dev tools debugger the `$scope.topic` variable is a Promise, resolved property with false.

Comment: Oh Sorry, my fault. I missed one thing that whenever you use a resource model it actually not directly gives you promise object but it returns an object that contains `$promise`. So you need to add callback on that object. I've updated the answer. Check it out.